# Can I build a data frame by extracting specific cell of data from mutliple excel files in a folder by using for loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to build a data frame with only a few cells of information from each excel file in a folder containing 1000+ files, with each cell of information being an entry in a column for that file. I was trying to use a for loop to read each file and extract a specific cell as a vector for each file in the folder. I also tried using bind_cols to bind each file by column into the data frame to have one table displaying the information. Below is the code I have so far, thanks for the help!

```
#Set directory of files
file.names<-list.files(path="Foreign Materials", pattern = ".xlsx", full.names=TRUE)

#Create empty data frame with desired data
foreignmat<-data.frame(date=numeric(),time=numeric(),,area=character(),
report=numeric(),incident=character(),material=character())

#Loop to read and pull desired data
for(file in file.names){
excel_data<-lapply(file.names,read_excel)
date(file)<-excel_data[8,3]
time(file)<-excel_data[2,7]
area(file)<-excel_data[2,5]
report(file)<-excel_data[2,2]
inc_type(file)<-excel_data[2,11]
mat_type(file)<-excel_data[7,11]
#Binding each iteration of data reading into one data frame
fmat<-bind_cols(excel_data)
}

#Print data frame to new excel file
library(readxl)
write.xlsx(fmat,"Foreign Materials.xlsx"
```

I am getting error messages saying the dimensions do not match when specifying the cell location of each variable although they are within the bounds of the matrix dimensions. Thank you again for any help!

Comment: Without sample data to confirm, I can't be definitive, but here's a couple of things to try: 1) you create an empty df called foreignmat to store your results but inside your loop you're feeding your data into an object called fmat. So ensure these names match; 2) given the structure of your data, I think you want `bind_rows()` instead of `bind_cols()`. Try those edits, and try again. Tag me in a comment to see if this helps or not.

Comment: Hello @L Tyrone , I tried those edits but still get the error 'Error in excel_data[8, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions' so I think the main problem in pulling one cell of data from a specific row/column of an existing data frame.

Comment: Ok. You'll need to add an example of your data to your question. To do this: 1) manually import the first .xlsx file your for loop calls into R and name it df; 2) run `dput(df)` and copy the result into a codeblock.

Comment: @LTyrone I figured out the issue, the data frame was actually formatted as a tibble with lapply and the [[x,y]] formatting was needed but thank you for the help!